# Omnet++ How to inherit from cSimpleModule in different project in the same workspace?

Tags: c++, eclipse, omnet++

I'm new to OMNeT++ and C++

I want to reproduce the environment for the libPTP:
https://omnetpp.org/download-items/libPTP.html

and I'm having trouble setting up the project OMNeT_Utils as a dependency for libPTP.
https://github.com/w-wallner/OMNeT_Utils

Problem:
I have imported the OMNeT_Utils into the same workspace as INET.
If I try to build the project, I get a console error for the file CallableModule.h "expected class-name before ',' token.

cSimpleModule is somehow not recognized.

It seems to be somehow a linking problem.
Any Ideas?

Using Omnet++ 5.6
INET 4.1
Linux Debian 9

I've tried to include the path ../omnetpp-5.4.1/include/omnetpp
where the csimplemodule.h is with C/C++ General --> Paths and Symbols.
But there was no effect.
csimplemodule.h is included by omnetpp.h

CallableModule.h

```
...
#include "ICallableBase.h"
#include <omnetpp.h>
#include <stack>
...

class cCallableModule : public cSimpleModule, public virtual ICallableBase
{
    private:

        // Resources
        std::stack<cMethodCallContextSwitcher *>    ContextStack;
....
};
```

csimplemodule.h

```
class SIM_API cSimpleModule : public cModule //implies noncopyable
{
    friend class cModule;
    friend class cSimulation;
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using OMNeT++ 5.4.1 and INET 4.1 however the project states that it need OMNeT 4.x (preferable 4.6) and Inet 2.x to build. Unless you intend to port everything I would advise to strictly follow the installation guide and try to upgrade the other components only when everything is already running. OMNeT++ 4.6 and 5.x was a major upgrade with several changes to the API, likewise both INET 3.0 and 4.0 was a major change, so you should not expect that project to work with the new versions.

Comment: OK. Will try to find a different way to setup a ptp simulation with OMNeT 5.4 and INET4. Because I intend to use OMNeT 5.4 for other future simulations and protocols. Thanks anyway.